# Updating a column with a function in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have this column in my database, called id which contains INTS.

e.g:

```
{id: 123456}  
{id: 234567}  
{id: 345678}  
{id: 456789}  
{id: 567890}
```

and I need to update these values with it's encrypted values by calling a function encryptId(id). encryptId takes in a LONG and then returns a STRING value

My thought process is to use .withcolumn to replace the current id column with the encrypted value

`db.withColumn("id", encryptId(col("id")))` gives me the error

```
type mismatch. Required: Long, found: column
```

`db.withColumn("id", encryptId("id"))` gives me the error

```
type mismatch. Required: Long, found: string
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? :(

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but on the second command you are missing a double quote at the end of "id": `db.withColumn("id", encryptId("id"))` instead of `db.withColumn("id, encryptId("id"))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't register `encryptId` as spark UDF. Let's assume that `encryptId` is defined as following:

```
val encryptId = (id: Long) => {
    // dummy implementation for simplicity   
    id.toString
}
```

You can register `encryptId` as UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val encryptIdUdf = udf(encryptId)
```

Now you can use `encryptIdUdf` as following:

```
db.withColumn("id", encryptIdUdf(col("id")))
```

Comment: what if it isn't a udf? it's a function taken from a library

Comment: You can't use a function that is not defined as udf as part of spark's dataframe transformations